# How do I get 2 seperate GPUs (gtx1060 and gt710) to make one big screen using two displays on Manjaro?

Tags: gnu-screen, manjaro, display, gpu

As of now, I have installed the non-free proprietary unvidia-drivers on my Manjaro setup, with only one screen showing. Both GPUs however AND displays are detected.
[Proof.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JgpKR.png)

I also notice that on the `X server display configuration` my second monitor is disabled. Thus, I tried to enable it, whilst I got rejected from applying due to [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/W9yGL.png) message.

I followed the instructions and saved the config to the X config file and even tried to edit the xorg config and rebooting, but to no avail.

After some research I tried assigning each mode and output directly from terminal using `randr` but again, greeted with an error message:

```
> xrandr --output VGA-1-0  --mode 1280x1024  --rate 144.00 --output DVI-D-0 --mode 1400x1050 --rate 60.00
xrandr: Configure crtc 4 failed
X Error of failed request:  BadValue (integer parameter out of range for operation)
  Major opcode of failed request:  140 (RANDR)
  Minor opcode of failed request:  21 (RRSetCrtcConfig)
  Value in failed request:  0x0
  Serial number of failed request:  74
  Current serial number in output stream:  74
```

Please do tell me what else I'd need to provide for you to be able to assist this Linux newbie.

Comment: What you are looking for, is the nvidia-specific feature "TwinView". Can you show your xorg.conf?

Comment: https://pastebin.com/LpGGV5fT here you go!

Comment: Hm… I was wrong. Apparently, TwinView can provide one screen on multiple displays, but on one card only. Maybe you can try Xinerama? It has limitations. Apparently, with Xinerama, you cannot move applications from one card to another as transferring the data (i.e. video memory) is non-trivial.

Comment: I looked up xinerama and found this tool _Wide guy_ , claiming to set up xinerama for you but, as expected, did absolutely nothing... Do you have any suggestions on what I can read / where to start?